# linux cmp utility output: what is a "line"?

Tags: linux, unix, cmp

Could someone tell me what the "line" number represents in the output of a cmp command?  I ask this because, first, I can't find it explained anywhere.  Second, I am getting results comparing a set of files where the "char" outputs are identical (as expected) but the "line" outputs differ wildly.

Comment: Not Linux-specific at all, by the way -- this is all black-letter POSIX. (Also, there *isn't* just one `cmp` release, or even just one Linux cmp; the GNU one is most popular, but many Linux-based systems use the busybox implementation instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "line" outputs reflect the number of newline characters seen prior to that point in the file.

For a file which is not in a textual format, the "line" output is not likely to be meaningful, and can be ignored; for a file which *is* in textual format, the line number returned could be used in a text editor to navigate to the area with the difference.

---

Per [the POSIX spec for `cmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/cmp.html):

> For files which are not text files, line numbers simply reflect the presence of a <newline>, without any implication that the file is organized into lines.

---

Because by default `cmp` prints only the first difference seen, the line numbers between both files are guaranteed to be identical at that point. When passed `-l`, `cmp` continues beyond the first difference -- but no longer prints line numbers, thus avoiding any ambiguity as to which file's line number count is canonical.